# Rx buffer overwrites Tx buffer in spidev xfer2

Tags: python, pi-3b+, spi, raspberry-pi-os

Coming here from electronics SE as it was suggested that I post here on this issue. The electronics SE [post is here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554709/rx-buffer-overwrites-tx-buffer-in-spidev-xfer2).

I'm setting up a comms link between an STM32F407 MCU and the Pi3B+. The Pi is running on the standard Raspberry Pi OS and with the SPI clock set to 10MHz. 8-bit word lengths on both ends. Simple hookup wires are used (for now) to connect the two. The code shown below works but when the data is printed out, it looks like the RX buffer overwrites the TX one that was sent. How do I stop that? I could clone the TX buffer before sending it but then I'll have to keep switching between buffers for further communications (before `spi.close()`). The console output is shown below the code.

```
import spidev
from time import sleep
from tabulate import tabulate  # pip3 install tabulate

ARRAY_SIZE = 56

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.mode = 0
spi.max_speed_hz = 10000000
spi.bits_per_word = 8

tx1 = [0xCA, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
       0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00]

# Do an SPI transaction
# rx1 is the receive buffer
rx1 = spi.xfer2(tx1)

# Print the RX and TX arrays
headers = ['array #', 'TX', 'RX']
idx = range(0, ARRAY_SIZE, 1)
table = zip(idx, tx1, rx1)

print(tabulate(table, headers=headers))

# close the SPI port
spi.close()
```

The console output looks like this,

```
  array #    TX    RX
---------  ----  ----
        0     0     0
        1     0     0
        2     0     0
        3     0     0
        4     0     0
        5     0     0
        6     0     0
        7     0     0
        8     0     0
        9     0     0
       10     0     0
       11     0     0
       12     0     0
       13     0     0
       14     0     0
       15     0     0
       16     0     0
       17     0     0
       18     0     0
       19     0     0
       20     0     0
       21     0     0
       22     0     0
       23     0     0
       24     0     0
       25     0     0
       26     0     0
       27     0     0
       28     0     0
       29   254   254
       30   255   255
       31   134   134
       32   254   254
       33   204   204
       34   254   254
       35   253   253
       36     0     0
       37     0     0
       38     0     0
       39     0     0
       40     0     0
       41     0     0
       42     0     0
       43     0     0
       44     0     0
       45     0     0
       46     0     0
       47    54    54
       48    84    84
       49    52    52
       50   108   108
       51     0     0
       52     0     0
       53     0     0
       54     0     0
       55     0     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be odd behaviour.

Can't help with the spidev module.

Perhaps use a different library.

My pigpio, lgpio, and rgpio Python modules will work okay.

pigpio (own SPI driver)

```py
import pigpio

tx1 = [0xCA, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
       0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00]

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
   exit()

h = pi.spi_open(0, 10000000, 0)

status, rx1 = pi.spi_xfer(h, tx1)

print(status, rx1, tx1)

pi.spi_close(h)
```

lgpio (uses Linux SPI driver)

```py
import lgpio as sbc

tx1 = [0xCA, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
       0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00]

h = sbc.spi_open(0, 0, 10000000)

status, rx1 = sbc.spi_xfer(h, tx1)

print(status, rx1, tx1)

sbc.spi_close(h)
```

Both produce the following

```
(56L,
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'),
[202, 254, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0,
 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks! I installed pigpiod from (your?) website and followed the instructions. Everything went smoothly till I tried to start the daemon. Then it gave me the error: `2021-03-23 23:09:59 initInitialise: Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid
Can't initialise pigpio library`

Comment: When I tried to check the status, it shows me this: `pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: pigpio is installed by default.  I suggest you do `sudo killall pigpiod` to get a clean state and then run `sudo pigpiod` to start the daemon.

Comment: Strange but I still see the same `inactive (dead)` message. I rebooted the Pi too and it is still the same. Do I need to set any pre-requisites via raspi-config?

Comment: Also, I was trying `lgpio` and when I try and run the python code, I get this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lgpio.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lgpio as sbc
  File "/home/pi/ld/lgpio.py", line 16, in <module>
    h = sbc.spi_open(0, 0, 10000000)
AttributeError: module 'lgpio' has no attribute 'spi_open'`

Comment: Not having much joy are you.  To see if the daemon is running enter the command `pigs t`.  If you get a number it is running.  How did you install lgpio?

Comment: Unfortunately no! :/ I installed `lgpio` by following the instructions listed on this [page](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/download.html). When I run `pigs t` I get `3978251194`

Comment: So the daemon is running.  Just run your pigpio script.  The error you get with lgpio is what you would get if you have named your script lgpio.py (it assumes the local script is the lgpio modue).  Make sure that has not happened.

Comment: Ah, I see! `lgpio` works and I see the data received from the MCU board. `pigpio` gives me the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pigpio_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pigpio
ImportError: bad magic number in 'pigpio': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'`Thanks again for helping me out on this! I've been stuck with `spidev` issues for a while now and there is very minimal support for it.

Comment: Not sure what is going on with pigpio.  It might be a conflict between the way it is pre-installed and the way it is installed manually.  lgpio may be the better way for your needs.